# Google sign in Firebase auth, show "choose account"

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-authentication

Hello I'm using firebase and google sign in. Everything works fine, but I don't know how to show "choose account" dialog. It doesn't appear when user isn't in firebase auth users and when it is. I would like to show this dialog. This is how I create auth (it is in fragment)

```
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.key))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()), this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
  // and start activity

  Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 4):

That's because you didn't sign out your google account (not Firebase). Try to sign out your google account:

```
signOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        signInClient.signOut();        //here

        nameTextView.setText("Google Account Name");

        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Sign out successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This dialog appears automaticly when there are different accounts set in the device.

Comment: ok I have registered one account on my phone (in settings) I want to login using another account I have to log out (in phone settings) from one account to login another?

Comment: You don' t need to do that, just set all accounts you want in the device and when you make the google sign in request, all these options should be available